# Fortran read from fie into arrays

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I need to read from a txt file into three arrays in order to calculate distances between coordinates. I have looked through other answers and pieced together the script bellow. The columns of the input file need to be come my x, y and z arrays respectively. There are 64 rows and 16 decimal places for each entry. Pointers would be greatly appreciated.

the data format:

```
0.8607595188703266  0.9252035918116585  0.4094258340665792
  0.5246038490998378  0.9804633529144733  0.5325820695466118
  0.6955271184611949  0.3304908806613460  0.7154502550542654
```

and my script so far:

```
PROGRAM readtest

use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env

implicit none

integer, parameter :: ArrayLen = 64
real(real64), DIMENSION(ArrayLen) :: x
real(real64), DIMENSION(ArrayLen) :: y
real(real64), DIMENSION(ArrayLen) :: z
integer :: i, ReadCode, num



OPEN(1, FILE='contcar.txt', STATUS='old', ACTION='read')
OPEN(2, FILE='xyz.txt', STATUS='replace', ACTION='write')

num = 0
ReadLoop: do i=1, ArrayLen

   read (1, '(A,F18.16)', iostat=ReadCode ) x(i), y(i), z(i)

   if ( ReadCode /= 0 ) then
      if ( ReadCode == iostat_end ) then
         exit ReadLoop
      else
         write ( *, '( / "Error on read: ", I0 )' )  ReadCode
         stop
      end if
   end if

   num = num + 1

end do ReadLoop

WRITE(3, 100) x, y, z
100 format (A,F18.16)

END PROGRAM readtest
```

The xyz.txt is appearing blank and I am not getting any errors at this stage, what is wrong here that is stopping the array filling and writing to the file?
Sorry, if this is too much of  mess to approach, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what you posted was very helpful, thank you, you answered a question I had yet to ask.

Comment: Yes, I spotted that a few mins ago and corrected. Output file is now populated but not at all right.

Comment: Good point. I think it might be best if I start this afresh tomorrow and de-clutter the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: What is a `fie`? (check title for typos)

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems with you approach:

- Your format specifications are wrong
- Your write won't do what you want

First off, the format `A,F18.16` reads two items, a character and a floating point number.  What you want is to read 3 floating point numbers.   With the file provided, there are two spaces before each number so you could use

```
read (1, '(3(2X,F18.16))', iostat=ReadCode ) x(i), y(i), z(i)
```

but this is not very flexible if your input format changes and it is easier to just do list-directed input:

```
read (1, *, iostat=ReadCode ) x(i), y(i), z(i)
```

which will do what you want and is not sensitive to the exact positioning of the numbers within the file and how many intervening spaces exist.

This will load your data into the arrays.  Now for output you want the same thing.  You want to duplicate the output so we can use the first format about to stipulate that output `(3(2X,F18.16))`. This will output 3 numbers per line with 2 spaces before each number.  The next problem is that you are attempting

```
WRITE(3, 100) x, y, z
```

which will transpose your array.  It will write all of the `x`, then all of the `y` and lastly all of the `z`.  If you want the same output, put it in a loop.  Putting the above together, use:

```
do i=1, ArrayLen
   WRITE(2, 100) x(i), y(i), z(i)
end do
100 format (3(2X,F18.16))
```

As a note, don't use single digit unit numbers, particularly the first few which conflict with system defined standard input/output/error units on most compilers.